# Xamarin forms: How to add a contentpage having arguments into a list?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, master-detail

I am implementing the `Navigation Drawer` on my project. I am following this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-master-detail-page-in-xamarin-forms/) for this feature.

**Mainpage.xsml.cs:**

```
public partial class NavigationDrawerPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();

            // Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(HomePage) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Setting", Icon = "setting.png", TargetType = typeof(SettingPage) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "LogOut", Icon = "logout.png", TargetType = typeof(LogoutPage) });

            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)));
        }
}
```

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="15">
                    <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
                  RowHeight="60"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
                  ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                         WidthRequest="30"
                         HeightRequest="30"
                         VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                         FontSize="Medium"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         TextColor="Black"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
```

**MasterPageItem.cs**

```
public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
```

**My problem is when adding my content pages to list. The above code working perfect:**

```
menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(SettingPage) });
```

**But I have a page having one argument, I can't add the argument inside of the `TargetType`.  See the below code:**

```
menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Help", Icon = "help.png", TargetType = typeof(HelpPage(false)) });  //showing syntax errors for this line
```

**How can I add a content page having arguments into the list item? Should I change the `TargetType` `datatype`?**

Comment: I assume you are using the `TargetType` to instantiate the Detail page. You could add a `Dictionary` to `MasterPageItem` that has default values and pass them after creating the Detail instance

Comment: @shanranm Can you share a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass parameters with the method `public static object CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)`;

#### Item

```
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }

    public object[] args { get; set; }   //
}
```

#### MasterDetailPage

```
menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(HomePage), args = new object[] {"string", 1 , false} } ); // pass parameters whatever you want

private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
    Type page = item.TargetType;
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page,item.args));   //this line
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

#### Add the constructor with corresponding parameters

```
public HomePage()   //remain the default constructor 
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public HomePage (string s , int i , bool b)   //add this
{
    InitializeComponent ();
}
```